# using proper join in oracle kindly solve the problem

Tags: mysql, oracle, join

[these are the table sructures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sD3Bg.jpg)i am trying to solve the question using outer join but cant

Display the saleman id and names of salesmen who have not made any sales.

Comment: A left join should work, please add your query.AND add your sample data as text together with expected output.

Comment: Are you using Mysql or Oracle?? They are not the same. Please Tag your questions with the right tags.

Answer (score 0):

As this is for homework, you can do it in two ways.

```
select salesman.sid,salesman.sname
from salesman
where not exists (select sale.sid
                  from sale
                  where sale.id=salesman.sid)
```

I am almost sure your teacher wants you to use not exists. But you can do it grouping too and counting the ones that have less than 1 results:

```
select salesman.sid,salesman.sname
from salesman left join sale on sale.sid=salesman.sid
group by salesman.sid,salesman.sname
having count(sale.saleid)<1
```